# How to only display results in a query where an ID column is displayed 3 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query, that displays transactions from customers.  What I'd like to do, is display only the results that have shown up 3 times during a time period.

For example:

if I do: `Select * from Table where dtcreated between @startdate and @enddate and result = 'Declined'`

```
lcustomerid      dtcreated      result
   1               8/1/15        Declined
   1               8/2/15        Declined
   1               8/3/15        Declined
   2               8/1/15        Declined
   2               8/2/15        Declined
   2               8/3/15        Declined
   3               8/1/15        Declined
   3               8/3/15        Declined
   4               8/1/15        Declined
```

What I'd like to do is display only those that have declined 3 times.  So above i would only like to see ID 1 and 2.

So the results i'm looking for are:

```
Select lcustomerid where dtcreated between @startdate and @enddate and result = 'Declined'

lcustomerid      
   1               
   2
```

Comment: _"only those that have declined 3 times"_ What if they have declined four times?

Comment: The way the software is written, they will not have anymore than 4.  That's why i requested 3 only.  But, the answer below satisfies that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
Select lcustomerid
from . . .
where dtcreated between @startdate and @enddate and result = 'Declined'
group by lcustomerid
having count(*) >= 3;
```